# Facebook Marketing API, Targeting Search - Search targeting by country AND city

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

From [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search#geo) you can search codes for all cities starting with dub like this:

```
curl -G \-d 'location_types=["city"]' \ 
-d 'type=adgeolocation' \ 
-d 'q=dub' \ 
-d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \ 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/search
```

I want to search for a city with a specific name in a specific country. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the additional parameter `country_code` to only search within a specific country.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search#geo

`country_code=US` would get you results in the US only.

Limiting the search by (numeric) `region_id` is also possible (but region is a level lower than country.)